# How can I put a slideshow in a webpage? I have used the following code but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I wanted to create a slideshow with 3 images inside a `div`. The slideshow will appear in a position at the top-left corner of the webpage. There are other divs and functionality in the web page as well.

I used this section of code inside the div for slideshow. I used mostly inline styles. The rest classes are just for positioning and size of the div.

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div role="list" class="banner__list w-dyn-items">
  <div style="background-image:url(/frontEnd/5a10aaa4d85f4b0001a5419a_2017-lamborghini-huracan-spyder-orange-exterior-front-angle-royalty-exotic-cars.jpg)" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(/frontEnd/5a10aaa4d85f4b0001a541d8_2015-bentley-continental-gtc-red-car-hero-2-image-royalty-exotic-cars.jpg)" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(/frontEnd/5abda7fc38a916291e1647d3_2018-jeep-wrangler-white-isolated-front-angle-royalty-exotic-cars.jpg)" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

The dots are not even appearing. the first image is appearing only. whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slide show works, you just can't see the images because they're background images, and without styles or content the `div`s have a `0px` width and height. Setting that shows the image correctly:

```
.banner__item {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

As a side note, if you put those images in the HTML as actual `img` tags, you don't need to specify the width and height. This has the added benefit of allowing you to use the `alt` attribute, which improves accessibility.

Also, inline styles can cause headaches down the road. Applying the styles via classes can clean up the markup, and make things easier to maintain in the long run.

Along with inline styles, inline JS can cause headaches too. You can move the inline `onClick` handlers into an event listener, to get the markup cleaner still. In the snippet, I've added the listener:

```
window.addEventListener("click", currentSlide);
```

To account for the click listener, rather than passing in the index I looked it up:

```
function currentSlide(event) {
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  const clickIndex = Array.from(dots).indexOf(event.target);
  showSlides(clickIndex);
}
```

I also modified the showSlides logic to just use 0 based arrays, rather than subtracting 1 from the integer passed in. Hopefully it all still works for you! :)

If you're wanting to center things, I usually reach for [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) these days!

You can see it working on with how you have it in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mathieujonson/pen/oNbVYPE), or with recommended changes in the snippet below:

```js
showSlides(0);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(event) {
  const dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  const clickIndex = Array.from(dots).indexOf(event.target);
  showSlides(clickIndex);
}

function showSlides(slideIndex) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex].className += " active";
}

window.addEventListener("click", currentSlide);
```

```css
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner__list {
  width: 100px;
}

.banner__item {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.banner__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div role="list" class="banner__list w-dyn-items">
  <div role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50/bada55" alt="green square" />
  </div>
  <div role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50/990000" alt="red square" />
  </div>
  <div role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/50/000099" alt="blue square" />
  </div>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
  <span class="dot"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It really worked.But problem is, those dots arent positioned in the center. I tried both float: left and text-align: center. But not working. Can you please help me centered them? TIA

Comment: I usually use flexbox for centering, FWIW. I updated the snippet and answer to include it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Thats all I wanted. I really appreciate it. I am new to this platform. Thats why I amnot able to give upvote yet. But I promise , as soon as I am given the ability to upvote I will upvote your answer.

Comment: Accepting the answer helps, too! It all adds to the fake internet points :)

Comment: sorry for disturbing you again. is it possible to use hoover to change slides instead of clicking the dots? I tried but everything became so messy.

Comment: Instead of a window listener, and a listener to the dots, and listen for the [mouseenter event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those other classes you told about are overwriting some of your code.

I just added `width` and `height` properties to your `banner__list` div and it worked well. I also added some border colors for showing the images are really changing.

See:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
<div role="list" class="banner__list w-dyn-items" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  <div style="border: 3px solid red; background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/300); width: 100%; height: 100%;" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <div style="border: 3px solid green; background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/300); width: 100%; height: 100%;" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <div style="border: 3px solid blue; background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/300); width: 100%; height: 100%;" role="listitem" class="banner__item w-dyn-item mySlides">
  </div>
  <span class="dot" style="cursor: pointer; 
                                             height: 15px;
                                             width: 15px;
                                             margin: 0 2px;
                                             background-color: #bbb;
                                             border-radius: 50%;
                                             display: inline-block;
                                             transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
                                             float:left;
                                             text-align:center;" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" style="cursor: pointer; 
                                             height: 15px;
                                             width: 15px;
                                             margin: 0 2px;
                                             background-color: #bbb;
                                             border-radius: 50%;
                                             display: inline-block;
                                             transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
                                             float:left;
                                             text-align:center;" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" style="cursor: pointer; 
                                             height: 15px;
                                             width: 15px;
                                             margin: 0 2px;
                                             background-color: #bbb;
                                             border-radius: 50%;
                                             display: inline-block;
                                             transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
                                             float:left;
                                             text-align:center;" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It really worked.But problem is, those dots arent positioned in the center. I tried both float: left and text-align: center. But not working. Can you please help me centered them? TIA

Comment: You can give them a parent, just by puting all the dots inside of a div, and then you add to that div the following properties:  width: 100%; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;. That should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me. Thats all I wanted. I really appreciate it. I am new to this platform. Thats why I amnot able to give upvote yet. But I promise , as soon as I am given the ability to upvote I will upvote your answer.

Comment: That's ok, I'm new too and I'm happy to help. Wish you good luck with your project(s)!

Comment: sorry for disturbing you again. is it possible to use hoover to change slides instead of clicking the dots? I tried but everything became so messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Twitter's Bootstrap. It has a slideshow component.

Add this to your style:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And here's the sample template:

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="[IMAGE-1-SOURCE]" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="[IMAGE-2-SOURCE]" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="[IMAGE-3-SOURCE]" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```